# Redirect static html URL to an .htaccess rewritten URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have fully static website, now I want to change this website to dynamic. But problem is that static website having good traffic and I do not want to lose that traffic. For the dynamic website I already rewrite the URL using htaccess for SEO reasons. I want to redirect the static url to the rewritten url (which was written by my .htaccess).

**(A) Static URL :**

```
www.website.com/examples/java/datatype/boolean/printbooleanvalue.html
```

**(B) Original Dynamic URL:**

```
www.website.com/examples.php?language=?java&category=data-type&subcategory=boolean&exampleurl=print-boolean-value
```

**(C) Rewritted Dynamic URL :**

```
www.website.com/examples/java/data-types/boolean/print-boolean-value
```

So I want to redirect `URL(A) to URL(C)`. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` file in the question.

Answer (score -1):

**Your .htaccess code:**

```
Redirect /examples/java/datatype/boolean/printbooleanvalue.html http://www.website.com/examples/java/data-types/boolean/print-boolean-value
```

**In any case you run into the need to redirect:**

```
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://yoursite.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

Answer (score -1):

You can hardcode the mod rewrite to load the php file when the html file is called.

The SEO friendly url that you have created in your `.htaccess` is redundant. Instead of the SEO friendly URL, use the same url as your original site.
For example in your `.htaccess` file write the rule like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule examples/java/datatype/boolean/printbooleanvalue.html$ /examples.php?language=?java&category=data-type&subcategory=boolean&exampleurl=print-boolean-value [L]
```

This will load the php file whenever the original html file is requested and it will use the same url as the older one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: He asked to redirect via .htaccess.

Comment: Ok, removed all other options, just showing the one using .htaccess.